# Localhost port does not change

Tags: python-3.x, flask, next.js, backend

How to fix app running on wrong port problem? Any solutions?

I am expecting localhost to be running in port 8080 instead of 5000.

I have tried to run port 8080 thourgh terminal, but does not work.
Port 5000 does not work properly with the thing I am trying to do.

`app.run(debug=True, port=8080)`

but terminal says port 5000 in use? What to do?

Comment: You need to include the error log on the terminal especially a log for port 8080 error. You can copy and paste the log or screenshot your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, including it properly in the run method. However, we cannot find the issue, since you did not show your full code initializing the app.
Alternatively, you can try to start the app via the Terminal with `flask run --port 8080`, or set it as additional run variable within your IDE.